# can compiled perl v5.28.0 from src (with gcc 4.8.5) run on RHEL 5.5?

Tags: gcc, redhat, rhel, perl

My question is about whether if it would be possible to run a compiled perl 5.28.0 from source (with GCC 4.8.5 on CentOS 7) to be able to be used on RHEL 5.5 (Tikanga) where GCC version is lower and so would be the other libs like libc, glibc, etc.

Our production environment is running very old perl version (5.8.8) and due to  security concerns, it is under heavy lock down, i.e. most of our servers lack make, gcc and related tools and there is no root access available to anyone

I was wondering if it would be possible to compile perl from source i.e. latest 5.28.0 with GCC 4.8.5 AND try to use this compiled version on our production servers (with GCC 4.8.2).

This will save me tonnes of headaches with slow bureaucracy and I can get going with my project with the new tools.

Have not been able to find any discussion or hint about this subject. Can anyone shed some light?

Thank you in advance.

**Update after 2 days:**

As it seems Perl 5.28 compiled on RHEL7 does not work on RHEL5.5. You will have to compile it on RHEL5.5 and make it relocatable for further usage on any server.

So I Downloaded the RHEL 5.5 and CentOS5.5 ISOs and ran into bootable iso related issues.

1. Couldn't make a suitable bootable disk for both rhel 5.5 and centos5.5.
2. rhel5.5 iso was a single dvd image and upon doing `file rhel5.5.iso` on command prompt, it showed bootable. tried unebootin, rufous iso creator, dd command and created ISOs and tried all of them one by one, but couldn't get it to show boot menu. tried FAT, NTFS FS while making boot disk. Stuck here now.
3. Centos5.5 iso came in 8 pieces of 600mb files. Had to create a single iso image out of it and found some online procedure to do it and made one ISO file. Got boot menu and looked like it worked. But then it got hung up on doing some sort of source media check test and couldn't proceed further. Found a fix related article that you imprint md5sum on iso and it should work but it didn't.

Just now found something on [grokbase](http://grokbase.com/t/centos/centos/111eqbxh95/how-to-convert-7-cd-iso-images-into-one-dvd-image) and it mentions a new technique, that could take me forward from the point of failure mentioned in point no.3 above.

Comment: Probably, although a lack of `make` will cause difficulties. Why don't you try it? [***How to build Perl from source code***](https://perlmaven.com/how-to-build-perl-from-source-code)

Comment: Hi, I am already preparing the setup on my local machine but its very time taking as I need to install a lot of packages. There is make and gcc available on one server and I can do the building there. But no internet access so won't be able to install any packages and I am not sure how to install package by package, as wget and curl don't work. its blocked. Plan is to do the building here, split it into chunks, download from work place, chunk by chunk, and then try to put it to use.

Comment: @Borodin I am already using that link to build from source.

Comment: Why are you installing packages before you have Perl working? You can download the Perl sources wherever you like and transfer them on a USB drive. You can also use [`CPAN::Mini`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::Mini) to keep a local copy of the CPAN library.

Comment: *"download from work place, chunk by chunk"* Why? It's not so big that you will fill an ordinary flash drive!

Comment: @Borodin: I work at a bank. Flash drives/HDDs/Laptops are not allowed. Most of the download websites are blocked. Any large file, say more than 10-15 mb gets flagged and it gets by scanners and network team as they are paranoid about security. Its an investment bank.

Hence the 'Chunk by chunk' (meaning small files of maybe 4-5 mbs each).

I just finished building the 5.28 version of perl with GCC 4.8.5, and also installed all my desired modules. I will now make split it and try to download them all tomorrow and check. Will update again. I hope that it works.just worried abt lib errors..

Comment: @Borodin the compiled version doesn't work on RHEL 5.5. It throws glibc related errors as it was compiled with newer glibc. I tried the cpanmini option, and the issue is that it has dependencies (LWP::UserAgent, File::HomeDir, URI) which can be arranged but we need the cpanmini first. Kind of circular problem. Now looking into how to make cpanm forcefully pickup dependencies from the local directory only. There must be a way.

Comment: Download the modules you need and install them manually. [`perlmodinstall`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html) has the information. This won't install any dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: [static compilation](http://p3rl.org/staticperl) bypasses the problems you are cautious about. You need to figure out whether the result is suitable for your intended purposes.

---

Otherwise you contend with traditional compilation like you had planned. If the libc is too different, it won't work. You could certainly just go ahead and try, then you'll know for certain.

The real solution is to set up a copy of your production environment (can be in a virtual machine) and compile stuff there.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions: VM and Static Perl. I am looking into them both. Unfortunately the build I created yesterday was destined to fail anyways as later on I found out that one cannot move the final created build as it has hard coded paths and exactly due to that, it was searching packages in that path only. Definitely VM is the right way to test and I am proceeding with that. Will update with progress soon.

Comment: [relocatable @INC](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/INSTALL#Relocatable-@INC)

Comment: Thanks @daxim I think this could make a big difference ;)
need to study the whole page now. It's got lots of info..

Answer (score 0):

You could try PerlApp + ActivePerl from ActiveState.com (maybe a part of PDK, Perl Development Kit). I've used it for many years. It compiles perl source and include modules (compiled modules also) into a .exe-program file on Windows and a binary executable file on Linux. There is a payed version and a free/demo version. The payed version allows for cross-compilation and more versions of Perl if I remember correctly.

You might run into trouble with differing versions of glibc/libc on dev vs prod computer, so try to use PerlApp on a CentOS 5.5 Linux (free) for compilation. CentOS5.5 resembles RHEL5.5 enough for most projects. Good luck.

Comment: Sir, me is looking only for free solutions ;) but thank you anyway(s). If need be, maybe I could tell my project team to go for this option. Isn't CentOS 5.5 kind of same code base apart from the proprietary RHEL stuff?

Answer (score -1):

Try [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) (is an admin-free perl installation management tool)

Comment: Hi, I am aware of perlbrew and basically its doing the same thing, building from source. The pain point here is to know whether if this strategy could work or not (i will find out, as I have finished building the perl version 5.28). As I mentioned, i don't have access to internet from servers and no root/sudo access. Basically I need something like a folder (which must contain everything pre-build) just to be used.